# Under what conditions does the fat in durum wheat semolina go rancid and how can you tell?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, fat

I have a packet of wholewheat couscous that is three months past its best before date but was stored in optimal, cool dry conditions. On opening the pack, there was a distinctive but not unpleasant "Oily" aroma, which I assume is from the fat it contains. The product looks fine, and is not discoloured or mouldy etc.

Having cooked a meal with with it, I couldn't taste anything obviously wrong, but my partner could taste something she couldn't quite put her finger on. We are both still alive after eating it with no ill effects, so I assume that a fresh pack would have the same aroma.

In lieu of purchasing another packet to test, is my wife right in thinking this has potentially gone off?

Comment: This doesn't feel like something that anyone who didn't also taste the couscous could tell you ...

Comment: It also goes to show how widely variable the sense and interpretation of taste and smell are. I have excellent sense of smell, whereas my wife seems more sensitive to taste.

Comment: Anyway, rancid whole wheat generally has a bitter aftertaste, if that helps.